# Cross-platform authentiated windows share

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to figure out how to access an *authenticated* windows file share from .net core (supplying domain / username / password) from Linux.

I have a .NET framework based 
sample project that does this in Windows operating system just fine. https://github.com/nddipiazza/SambaFetcher
(in particular
   https://github.com/nddipiazza/SambaFetcher/blob/master/SmbFetcher/UNCAccess.cs )

But it relies on the NetApi32.dll directly so it will not work from Linux.

Is there some way from .NET core to do this authentication?

Comment: maybe this: http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/#howtouse

Comment: I already tried JCIFS and SMBJ and errors from those are why i am trying a .net client alternative. JCIFS does not work - smb1 only. and SMBJ throws errors for certain servers. i will still try it. maybe they fixed something.

Comment: confirmed. see https://github.com/ume05rw/SharpCifs.Std/issues/17
therefore we cannot use sharpcifsstd

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary it supports SMB2 and has a client part.

Comment: I have never heard of that one. Very nice. I will try it!

Comment: Hey @SimonMourier do you know of anywhere with some examples of the use of this library?

Comment: nm - found it in the issues area

Comment: @SimonMourier you should convert that comment to answer. it is the correct answer to this question. library works great (lacks documentation but i'm going to try to help add some in from the work i'm doing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this library: [SMBLibrary](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary) which supports SMB2. I'll quote the description here:

> SMBLibrary is an open-source C# SMB 1.0/CIFS, SMB 2.0 and SMB 2.1
> server implementation.
>
> SMBLibrary gives .NET developers an easy way to
> share a directory / file system / virtual file system, with any
> operating system that supports the SMB protocol.
>
> SMBLibrary is
> modular, you can take advantage of Integrated Windows Authentication
> and the Windows storage subsystem on a Windows host or use independent
> implementations that allow for cross-platform compatibility.
>
> SMBLibrary shares can be accessed from any Windows version since
> Windows NT 4.0.

It's mostly for coding a server, but it also has a client part here: https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/tree/master/SMBLibrary/Client

Comment: Client examples moved to https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/blob/master/ClientExamples.md